# Using egrep within loop

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to loop through a list of usernames and print out groups they belong to, but omitting ones I'm not interested in. But it's not working. And no, I'm no shell script expert.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH

# This script runs through list of user IDs
# and spits out the groups they belong to 

while IFS= read -r line
    do
GROUPSS=$(groups $line)

RESULT=$(egrep -v "_unknown|sciences|everyone|netaccounts" $GROUPSS)
        echo $line $GROUPSS
done < $1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
RESULT=$(egrep -v "_unknown|sciences|everyone|netaccounts" $GROUPSS)
```

After the regex, `egrep` expects to find filenames on its command line.  The line above, however, provides it with a list of groups.  Fortunately, `egrep` can also accept input from stdin.  So, we can provide the list of groups there.

There is another catch, though.  `egrep` operates on a line at a time but the information in the `GROUPSS` variable is space-separated not newline-separated.  So, we need to change that.

Putting that all together:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    result=$(groups "$line" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | egrep -v "_unknown|sciences|everyone|netaccounts")
    echo $result
done < $1
```

On my system, `groups` returns the user name followed by a colon followed by the list of groups.  The pipeline does not remove the user name or colon.  Consequently, for output it is sufficient to use `echo $result`.

#### Variation

Some consider `tr` easier to use than `sed`.  For them, this alternative may be preferred:

```
results=$(groups "$line" | tr ' ' '\n' | egrep -v "_unknown|sciences|everyone|netaccounts")
```

Comment: I'm using OSX whose sed does not have the -r flag and -E does not appear to work initially...

Comment: Yup, the tr did work. Thank you! All good now, and your explanation is helpful. Cheers